# Row not getting updated after PostgresSql query

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

This is my simple query which deletes a row from table A and inserts it into table B with some additional columns. I still see the row in question in table A and not table B. But transaction shows successful with no errors.

```
with failed as (delete from transactions where transaction_id='12345' returning *)
insert into failed_notifications ("transaction_id") select "transaction_id" from failed;
```

Response I get from the postgres

```
Updated Rows    0
Query   with failed as (delete from transactions where transaction_id='12345' returning *)
        insert into failed_notifications ("transaction_id") select "transaction_id" from failed
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE public.failed_notifications (
    transaction_id text NOT NULL,
    "identity" text NULL,
    identity_type text NULL,
    country_id text NULL,
    updated_at int8 NULL,
    created_at int8 NULL,
    reason text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT failed_notifications_pkey PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.transactions (
    "identity" text NOT NULL,
    identity_type text NULL,
    service_id text NULL,
    partner_id text NULL,
    country_id text NULL,
    updated_at int8 NULL,
    created_at int8 NULL,
    transaction_id text NOT NULL,
    start_date int8 NULL,
    end_date int8 NULL,
    is_sms_triggered bool NULL,
    CONSTRAINT transactions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);
```

Comment: The response query is not the same as the one you show running.  I would look at the Postgres log to see what is going on?

Comment: Updated question. Nothing in the log, no log line with this query execution

Comment: Did you run query directly in database, or you are using some ORM (GORM, which you tagged)?

Comment: I'm using gorm.io in the code but to debug this running it vanilla sql in the psql console with same results at both places

Comment: When you run this in `psql` are you running with the default `autocommit` or are using a `BEGIN;` and then not issuing a `COMMIT;`?  Does `select from transactions transaction_id='12345'` return a result? Or is there maybe empty spaces in the string causing issues?

Comment: `select * from transactions where transaction_id='12345';` returns empty rows, while I see data in the table in DBeaver (have refreshed it). Not using a begin statement, the above queries are exactly as I have them.

Comment: So either; 1) You are working in different databases or schemas in a database or 2) `transaction_id` has empty spaces. Try `select * from transactions where trim(transaction_id)='12345';`

Comment: 1) not possible because simple inserts are getting added in the same table. 2) same empty rows.

Comment: 1) Inserts from where `psql`, dBeaver, somewhere else? 2) Then the conclusions are a) That you are looking at two different tables, either different databases or different schemas. Verify that what you are looking at in `psql` and `dBeaver` are the same. b) If you thoroughly explored a) and you are the same table then it maybe an indexing issue. Reindex the `transaction_id` column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243071/discussion-between-riser101-and-adrian-klaver).

Comment: do you have triggers or rules defined on your tables ? If so can you share the trigger functions and rules definition ?